# Login incorrect after reboot

Tags: centos, users, login, password

After reboot my centos 7 login is not working.
I can't login, it always appears "login incorect".

I remember that the last significant change I made was in the file "sudoers". I added:

```
username    ALL=NOPASSWD: ALL
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can break the CentOS password Using below mention steps.

1.Reboot the system.

2.Interrupt the boot loader countdown by pressing any key.

3.Move the cursor to the entry that needs to be booted.

4.Press <kbd>e</kbd> to edit the selected entry.

5.Move the cursor to the kernel command line (the line that starts with

```
linux16
```

Append to that line:

```
rd.break
```

(this will break just before control is handed from the initramfs to the actual system).

6.Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd> to boot with the changes.

```
# mount -o remount,rw /sysroot
# chroot /sysroot
# chage -l root
# chage -E -1 root
# passwd root  
# touch /.autorelabel
Type exit twice.
```

The first will exit the chroot jail, and the second will exit the initramfs debug shell